# preview highlight shape

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I am using 10.8.5 with Preview V 6.0.1(765.6).

When I use Tools->Annotate->Highlight Text to select texts in order to highlight them, I expect it to be a rectangle region. But it is not, see the picture below.

Personally, I don't like it being this way (if this is not a bug). I tried 3 different PDF files, and I got the same results.

Is there any option to change this?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a feature, at least it behaves the same way in 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug, **it's a feature**, designed to replicate a real-life highlighter. The highlight feature works the same in the new iBooks, as well as iBooks for iOS. **There is currently no way to change this.**

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html